# Clicking on fb like button increases the counter by 2

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have the FB like button on main page and other pages. And the problem occurs only on the main page.

After clicking on FB like btn, counter increases by 1 and pop-up window for comments appears.

1. If I click 'Close', everething is Ok,
2. If I don't type any comments and click 'Post to Facebook', evereting is Ok too.
3. BUT if I type any text and click 'Post', then after the page reloading I can see that my counter increases one more time

I use the next js-code on my site:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&app_id=MY_CODE";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and that tag

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behavior since Like Button display not only `likes` count.

This is described in documentation for [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) social widget:

> **What makes up the number shown on my Like button?**
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> - The number of likes of this URL
> - The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
> - The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.